# Imageview width match_parent and need to horizontal center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have Imageview with height and width is match_parent. I need image in horizontal center **without** change width to wrap_content. You can change parent layout.

Here is my xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: just add android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" property to <ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ImageView    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

This should suite your need, If you need more info please look at : [scaletype description](http://etcodehome.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html)

Try the below code:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I need image in **only** horizontal center, not in parent's center.

Comment: android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
try this. you will get it,
p.s. have you tried the link, it is well explained.

Comment: I tried link. fill_parent and match_parent are same. I also tried fitStart. Image only in horizontal center not need to vertical center.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your issue.

Comment: open this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByV6R3ekQkzQRU05S0NiMlBxN1U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this is the property of the imageview itself, try android:layout_centerInParent="true" for the imageview. If you want you  can also try for linear layout and set the gravity for the layout. android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" can also be set to the imageview to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should try it with `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`. Rest depends on what your exact need is and what is the size of images you are displaying.

[For More Info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

**Edit**

If you want to center only the image in ImageView to horizontal center then add the following,

`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`

You should have the height to be `wrap_content`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: I need image in only horizontal center, not in parent's center

Comment: @SamP Why do you need the height and width of the image to be match_parent?